# Pandas Merging two dataframe creating mililons of records

Tags: pandas

I am having an issue that never happened before and was wondering if it's a bug coming from Panda library.

I have 2 dataframe of the following shape:

`df.shape = (27486, 6)`

`df_nova.shape = (24755, 11)`

I am merging to the left and therefore it shouldn't create more rows that there are already:

`df = df.merge(df_nova,how='left',left_on='Phone',right_on='phone')`

However the shape of DataFrame is now millions of rows (number of columns are correct:
(14283635, 16)

My version of Pandas is pandas==0.25.3

Comment: Your result can have as few as `27486` rows or as many as `27486*24755` rows. Your result is between that so I don't see the issue. It all depends how many duplicates you have on the keys. I.e. look at something as simple as `pd.DataFrame([1,2]).merge(pd.DataFrame([[2,2], [2,3]]), how='left')`

Comment: a pure Cartesian product will give you 680,415,930 rows....  so it's all down to your join columns

Comment: My understanding of left merge would that it merge right rows on left rows if and only if there is a match. The issue here seems that it created rows even when there is no match.